# Numerical recipes / Multidimensional root search (using newt) : How to minimize the maximum error

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, newtons-method

This question is related to the "numerical recipes in C++" book, so it will be reserved to people knowing a little about it as well as about multidimensional optimization.

I am writing a program that needs to search for a multidimensional root, and in order to solve it, I am using the multidimensional newton root finding method, namely the *"newt"* procedure.

For those interested in the details, I am trying to fit a deformable 3D model to a steresocopic view of an object, based on a few feature points (feature points which are seen by two cameras).

For this, I am using the newt procedure with the following :

- *11 Input parameters :* my deformable model can be modeled with 11 parameters (composed of 5 geometric parameters and 6 deegres of freedom for the 3D object location) :
- *14 Output parameters* for which I need to find the root : based on feature points which are identified by the camera, and given a set on "input parameters", I can calculate a set of distances between the feature points seen by the camera and their theoretical location. I have 7 of those points, so that gives me 14 parameters (7 distances times 2, since I calculate the distances on both cameras)

My problem is that I have more output parameters (14) than input parameters (11) : whenever I call "newt", the algorithm always converges, however it will find a solution that minimizes almost perfectly the 11 first output parameters, but that has lots of errors on  the 3 remaining parameters.

However I would like the errors to be uniformly divided among the output parameters.

I already tried the approaches described below :

1. Try to combine the 14 output parameters into 11 parameter (for
   example, you take the average of some distances, instead of using
   both distances). However I am not 100% satisfied with this approach
2. Mix several solutions with the following principle :

   - Call mnewt and memorize the found root
   - Change the order of the 14 output parameter
   - Calling mnewt again and memorize the found root
   - Compute a solution is the average of the two found roots

Does anyone know of a more generic approach, in which the root finding algorithm would favor an error that is uniformly divided among the output parameters, instead of favoring the first parameters?

Comment: Why not setup a single "distance metric", e.g. sum of squared distances over all your 7 feature points, and then run some optimization routine. Levenberg-Marquardt seems fitting.

Comment: I tried that already, and it was a failure. If you read the multidimensional optimization of the NR book, you will see (and I believe them) that it is a bad idea to try and tranform a multidim root search into a minimum search (as per your suggestion) : you end up trying to minimize a function which has *lots* of local minima and *lots* of flat zones in one direction (ie the derived on one component is null : a nightmare for newton-like methods)

Comment: However, I will try to run a minimization around the starting point given by newt. Maybe it will be less prone to converging to a false local minimum.

Comment: I tried again, and I confirm : minimization does not work here, since there are two many local minimas and too many flat zones even with a good starting point.

Comment: If you problem where a linear one, SVD (singular value decomposition) does exactly what you want. Perhaps you can re-code the Newton-Raphson step each time to use SVD instead of whatever it does to solve the linear approximation ?

Comment: Walter, I like your suggestion ! I do not yet have a linear expression for my problem, but I will try to express one.

Comment: @PascalT.: What minimization routines did you try with Pascal's method ? In similar situations, I recall that Levenberg-Marquardt performs poorly if you don't have an excellent first guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to minimize `F(x)` by solving `f(x)=0` where `x` is an m-dimensional vector and `f` maps this to an n-dimensional vector. Your optimization problem is **underdetermined** if `m < n` (in your case 11 < 14).

For such systems, the generic way to solve them is to minimize a vector **norm** on `x`. You can do this by minimizing the system `x^T A x + c f(x)^T f(x)` with respect to both `x` and the **Lagrange-multiplier** `c`. Without further information, you could take A to be the nxn **identity matrix**. This will find the `x` that solves `f(x)=0` while having the smallest norm.

For more details on doing this with Newton's method, see e.g. this [paper](http://www.pjaeckel.webspace.virginmedia.com/StabilisedMultidimensionalRootFinding.pdf).